# Can't disable firewall on CentOS 6.3

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, firewall

I'm trying to disable the firewall with no luck. I have tried:

- Going through System->Administration->Firewall and disabling it there.
- Running 'iptables -F' and then /etc/init.d/iptables save
- I've tried disabling SELinux

Whenever I reboot, the iptables rules are still there. If I run '/etc/init.d/iptables restore' then I get an empty list, but once I reboot all the rules are back. It seems like some other process is starting iptables and populating it with rules

Comment: execute `iptables -nL` and compare this with /etc/sysconfig/iptables to see if rules from this file are loaded if not try to find files in your system with rules currently loaded maybe then you find what app is using iptables

Comment: Execute 'service iptables stop' on redhat derivitives to stop a service.  (Only until next reboot)  Use chkconfig to disable services at  boot time.

Comment: Out of morbid curiosity, why do you want to completely disable iptables in the first place? You're just replacing it with a different firewall, right? Not... I mean you're not actually seriously considering not having a firewall at all, right?

Answer (score 3):

`/etc/sysconfig/system-config-firewall` contains a line that the gui seems to read to determine the firewall state.  Setting this to `--disabled` in addition to the `chkconfig iptables off` instructions seems to work for me.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure because I had never use CentOS 3 but in newer version disabling iptables on startup can be accomplished by executing:
`chkconfig iptables off`

Rules in Centos 5 and 6 are stored in /etc/sysconfig/iptables

Comment: I have disabled iptables with chkconfig. iptables is not configured to run on startup, but it looks like some other process is starting it up and adding rules.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible some other firewall software has been installed and enabled to start on boot that is using iptables. If the software uses traditional init scripts it is likely it has a file in /etc/init.d/. If that is the case you may be able to find it by looking for all init scripts with a reference to iptables by grepping through the init scripts, for example:

```
grep -li iptables /etc/init.d/*
```

The service would also likely be configured to start in your default runlevel, which you can identify and disable with the command chkconfig.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the /sbin/iptables binary with a script that told me things about the process.  Tracked the issue to libvirtd.  If you don't need libvirtd, try turning it off.  This worked for me.

Ben

Comment: libvirtd should only be adding _its own_ firewall rules, not restoring other rules.